# cloning elements with eventlistener

Tags: javascript, clone, addeventlistener, clonenode

im trying to clone elements when I click the button. So far, I don't know, what the problem is about my code. I think it looks kinda right, could you please look over, and tell/describe me the problem? I mean, I read a lot of documentation about clonenode, and I just do the same. And when I look over my code, it does make sense to me, but it doest want to work... D:
The button should clone the whole field(inputCar)

Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7k1sb7w0/

This is the html code:

```
<button id="buttonBtn">Clone Field</button>

<div id="inputCar">
  <div class="column">
    <label class="heading">Invite Persons</label>
  </div>
  <div class="medium-6 column">
    <label for="ext-name">Name</label>
    <input id="ext-name" type="text">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <label for="check7"></label>
    <label>BMW</label>

    <input type="checkbox" checked="true">
    <label for="check8"></label>
    <label>Ford</label>
  </div>

  <div class="medium-6 column">
    <label for="ext-mail">E-Mail</label>
    <input id="e-mail" type="email">
    <datalist id="members"></datalist>
    <button class="deletePerson">delete</button>
    <label class="delete_btn">delete Field</label>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>
```

and this is my jsfile:

```
var clickBtn = document.querySelector('#buttonBtn');
var field = document.querySelector('#inputCar');
var i = 0;

clickBtn.addEventlistener('click', function(e) {
  var cloneField = field.cloneNode(true);
  cloneField.id = "inputCar" + i++;
  field.parentNode.appentChild(cloneField);
}
```

Thank you in advance,
mark

Comment: How you write things actually matter, for instance you're missing parentheses, there's nothing called `addEventlistener`, it's `addEventListener` and same with `appentChild` which should be `appendChild` etc. Learn to type.

Comment: @adeneo aaah thank you :D how clumsy i am , always the problem with the typing^^